# win32gui.EnumWindows starting with invalid window handle?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I have been using this piece of code I made for a few months now to check if a certain group of windows I have open are stuck on a certain window title for a given amount of seconds, and then closes them if so. This code is continuously ran on my VPS.

```
import time
import datetime
import win32gui
import win32process

max_downtime = 90
pid_downtimes = {}
cur_pids = []
prev_pids = []

def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
    class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    window_text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)

    if class_name != "ConsoleWindowClass":
        return

    if not window_text.startswith("Plutonium"):
        return

    if "Server restarter" in window_text:
        return

    if "Dedicated Server" in window_text:
        return

    tid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

    if pid not in pid_downtimes:
        pid_downtimes[pid] = 0

    pid_downtimes[pid] += 1

    if pid_downtimes[pid] >= max_downtime:
        print("Server restarted at:", datetime.datetime.now())
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, 16) # close window
        return

    cur_pids.append(pid)


while True:
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    old_pids = [pid for pid in prev_pids if pid not in cur_pids]

    for pid in old_pids:
        if pid in pid_downtimes:
            del pid_downtimes[pid]

    prev_pids = cur_pids
    cur_pids = []

    time.sleep(1)
```

A few days ago, for the first time it crashed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 43, in <module>
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
line 12, in winEnumHandler
    class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.')
```

Anyone know what would cause this to crash after running smoothly for months? It seemed to have started the function `winEnumHandler` with an invalid window handle from `win32gui.EnumWindows`, which I didn't know was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[MS.Learn]: GetClassName function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **If the function fails, the return value is zero**. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

so this function **can** fail for certain windows (maybe there are some that don't have a class?). So your code must handle this scenario. Could be something like:

```py
import pywintypes

# ...

def win_enum_handler(hwnd, ctx):
    window_text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    try:
        class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    except pywintypes.error:
        class_name = "Could not be determined"

    # ...
```